# How to Parse date and time from JSON data and set reminders

Tags: android, datetime, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a JSON object containing date and time information, I want to retrieve the data and set reminders based on the date/time.

{"status":200,"message":"Success","result":[{,"Remainderid":"1"
                            "Remainder":"Birthday","Date":"2017-06-13 10:00:00"}]}

And My Code

```
 private void getReminder() {
    String url = Urls.current_date_view + "&Userid=" + Model.getInstance().userid;// Model.getInstance().userid;
    Log.e("RemindersUrl====>", "" + url);
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(getApplicationContext(), url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            reminsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            reminsList.clear();
            try {
                reminresponse = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
                if (reminresponse == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    /*{"status":200,"message":"Success","result":[{,"Remainderid":"1"
                        "Remainder":"Birthday","Date":"2017-06-13 10:00:00"}]}*/
                    remind_status = reminresponse.optString("status");
                    reminstatus_msg = reminresponse.optString("message");
                    if (remind_status.equalsIgnoreCase("200")) {
                        JSONArray array = reminresponse.getJSONArray("result");
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            String mTime = "", mDate = "";
                            String mIDs = object.getString("Remainderid");
                            String mTitle = object.getString("Remainder");
                            String curDate = object.getString("Date");


                            Calendar calendars = Calendar.getInstance();
                            Log.e("DATEANDmIDs====>", " " + mIDs + " ");

                            SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                            java.util.Date datemniles = f.parse(curDate);
                            calendars.setTime(datemniles);
                            mHour = calendars.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                            mMinute = calendars.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                            mYear = calendars.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            mMonth = calendars.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            mDay = calendars.get(Calendar.DATE);

                            mDate = mDay + "-" + mMonth + "-" + mYear;
                            mTime = mHour + ":" + mMinute;

                            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
                            mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
                            mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
                            mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
                            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
                            mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, mSec);
                            saveReminder(mIDs, mTitle, mTime, mDate);

                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });
}
```

SetRemainder Code

```
 public void saveReminder(String mIDs, String mTitle, String mTime, String mDate) {

    Intent intents=getIntent();
    int ID;
    String reminder="";

    // Check repeat type
    reminders = rb.getAllReminders();
    Log.e("remindersALL===>", "" + reminders);
    if (reminders.isEmpty()) {
    //AddSqliteDataBase
        ID = rb.addReminder(new Reminder_set(Integer.parseInt(mIDs), mTitle, mDate, mTime));
        getAlarams(ID);
    } else if (!reminders.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reminders.size(); i++) {
           reminder = String.valueOf(reminders.get(i).getID());
        }
        if (reminder.equalsIgnoreCase(mIDs+1)) {
            Log.e("WorkEquals===>", "" + reminder);
            getUpdates(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(mIDs)), mTitle, mDate, mTime);
        } else {
            ID = rb.addReminder(new Reminder_set(Integer.parseInt(mIDs), mTitle, mDate, mTime));
            Log.e("NotEqualsID===>", "" + reminder+"==="+mIDs+1);
            getAlarams(ID);
        }


    }
}

private void getAlarams(int ID) {
    Log.e("Alaram==>",""+"Workesd ==>" +ID);
    new AlarmReceiver().setAlarm(getApplicationContext(), mCalendar, ID);

}

private void getUpdates(String mIDs, String mTitle, String mTime, String mDate) {
    mReceivedReminder = rb.getReminder(Integer.parseInt(mIDs));
    mReceivedReminder.setID(Integer.parseInt(mIDs));
    mReceivedReminder.setTitle(mTitle);
    mReceivedReminder.setDate(mDate);
    mReceivedReminder.setTime(mTime);
    rb.updateReminder(mReceivedReminder);
}
```

Comment: get it as string and convert it to date

Comment: Can you show us some code on what have you done and what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**create a json object**

```
JSONObject data  = getJSONObject(response);
```

**To get a specific string**

```
String date = data.getString("Remindercurdate");
String Reminder = data.getString("Reminder");
```

**now convert String in to Date like this**

```
String mydate = date;// your date from json  
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");  
try {  
   Date Resultdate = format.parse(mydate);  
   Log.e("Date id ",""+Resultdate);  
  } catch (ParseException e) {  

   e.printStackTrace();  
 }
```